# EF Core non-existant column in query, how to rectify?

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, iqueryable

working my way through an EF core project I have inherited and am quite new when it comes to LINQ/EF core.

I'll cut this back to simplify things, and will demonstrate my problem with 4 basic tables.

**Customer**

| CustomerId | Name | Contact |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | john@gmail.com |
| 2 | Peter | peter@gmail.com |

**CustomerTrade**

| Id | CustomerId | OtherDetail |
| --- | --- | --- |
| T1 | 1 | xyz |
| T2 | 1 | abc |

**CustomerTradeParameter**

| ParamID | TradeId | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | 1 | 1234 |
| Y | 1 | 5678 |

**CustomerTradeParameterType**

| ParamID | Name | OtherGenericInfo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | Hello | *Null* |
| Y | Test | *Null* |

**Models**

```cs
public class Customer : AuditableEntity
{
    public long CustomerId { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Contact { get; private set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CustomerTrade> CustomerTradeList{ get; set; }

    protected Customer() 
    { }

public class CustomerTrade : AuditableEntity
{
    public long Id { get; private set; }
    public long CustomerId { get; private set; }
    public string OtherDetail { get; private set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CustomerTradeParameter> CustomerTradeParameterList { get; set; } = new List<CustomerTradeParameter>();

    protected CustomerTrade() // For EF Core
    { }

public class CustomerTradeParameter : AuditableEntity
{
    public long TradeId { get; set; }
    public string ParameterType { get; private set; }
    public string Value{ get; private set; }

    protected CustomerTradeParameter() // For EF Core
    { }
}
```

**DTOs**

```cs
public class CustomerTradeDto : AuditableDto
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long CustomerId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CustomerTradeParameterDto> CustomerTradeParameterList { get; set; } = new List<CustomerTradeParameterDto>();

}

public class CustomerTradeParameterDto : AuditableDto
{
    public long TradeId { get; set; }
    public string ParameterType { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

The below query is attempting to retrieve a specific trade, and a list of its relevant parameters.

```cs
IQueryable<CustomerTradeDto> foundTrade = _database.CustomerTrade
    .Select(trade => new CustomerTradeDto
    {
        Id = trade.Id,
        CustomerId = trade.CustomerId,
        CustomerTradeParameterList = trade.CustomerTradeParameterList.Select(param => new CustomerTradeParameterDto{
        
            ParameterType = param.ParameterType,
            TradeId = customerTrade.Id,
            Value = param.Value
            // (second question written further below) - If I wanted to additionally retrieve the CustomerTradeParameterType record 
            // (to get the name of this parameter), how would I embed this join? 
            // I originally had ParameterType defined as a "CustomerTradeParameterType" instead of a string, 
            // but am not sure how to add this extra join inside this select?

        }).ToList()
    })
    .Where(e => e.Id == find.Id);
```

The .Select on CustomerTradeParameterList is raising the following error:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'CustomerTradeId'.

I understand EF core is attempting to define a column that it is unsure of, but I am not sure how to fix this? The correct column is TradeId.

Secondly, I have an additional question regarding joins inside a sub .Select. In the query above I have a comment outlining the question.

Appreciate any tips you can provide!

Comment: What output you expect? Your question is not that much clear. Please edit it and elaborate more so we can provide a solution of your issue.

Comment: @KiranJoshi thanks for your comment. My query is attempting to retrieve a specific trade record with its list of parameters (as defined in the model). I supplied an error I received for a column that doesn’t exist and want to know how to fix. Does that clarify?

Comment: Where is `CustomerTradeId` in query I can not able to find it

Comment: It’s not. That’s the point. Despite being declared as TradeId, EF is somehow trying to select it as CustomerTradeId.

Comment: Have you check your DB? Is there any column name having `CustomerTradeId` is table? If it is then EF will not allow you to perform any operation. Does you are using Code First Approach?

Comment: The column does not exist. EF core is incorrectly calling it (not sure if it is based on the table name?) I’ve seen several other posts about the same thing but the scenarios look a bit different to mine and I can’t work it out